# Using msbuild I want to update a config file which resides in different server

Tags: msbuild

I am able to update the xml file if it is resides in our build server using below msbuild task

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="UpdateAttribute" File="$(RootPath)\WSProductServices\Config\INTAppSettings.config" XPath="/appSettings/add[@key='dbserver']" Key="value" Value="$(DBServerName)"/>
```

but now i want to update the xml file which resides in different server, any help how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: You could use psexec to start a remote msbuild process with an msbuild file which calls this task?

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution regarding how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? It's pretty simple: on your server you have an msbuild file with your XmlFile task, then on your client machine you have an msbuild file with something like `<Exec Command="psexec.exe \\srv -u username -p password C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe path\to\mytask.targets /t:XmlFileUpdate"/>`.

Comment: I have teamcity as my buildserver, my build script builds the application, makes the applications as packages and deploys these packages to different server using msdeploy.After deploying i want to update the config files like updating database name.

Comment: In that case: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803688/is-it-possible-to-modify-web-config-of-existing-site-using-msdeploy